# Canceling observable when certain observable emit data rxjs

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I have three source of data :

```
let insightsFromDB$;// Return observable of insight object
let insightsFromAPI$;// Return observable of insight object
let insightsFromWebsockets; // Return observable of insight object
     otherObservable$
       .merge(insightsFromDB$, insightsFromAPI$) // Return observable of insight object 
      .map(insight=>insight.likes)
```

I want to add the `insightsFromWebsockets$` to the `otherObservable$` in such a way that if it's emits a value, it cancels the insight object coming from the merge operator and emit the object coming from `insightsFromWebsockets$` to the map operator.

For more clarity, I have added the following marble diagram that summarize my code: 
[image]

Comment: Could you, perhaps, provide a [mcve]? Also, please read [ask].

Comment: @Enigmativity  Okay I am reading it, what the things missing in the question ?

Comment: Does your code compile? Can I copy, paste & run it?

Answer (score 2):

So if i understand your requirements correctly:

- you want to receive values from streams `x` and `z` (`merge`)
- once `z` emits you no longer are interested in values of `x` (`takeUntil`)

Example implementation:

```js
    var x = Rx.Observable.interval(300);
    var y = Rx.Observable.timer(1500, 500).mapTo('y');
    
    x.takeUntil(y)
      .merge(y)
      .take(8).subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.12/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Jasem Al-Yafie - `x` is `merge(insightsFromDB$, insightsFromAPI$)` while `y` is `insightsFromWebsockets`

Comment: Thank you, make very sense  :)